# Incompatible types issue

Tags: java

I am trying to run this program that has to contain a `Building` class that is extended by 2 other classes `TradeCenter` and `SportCenter`. The program has to print info for 3 buildings (array). The problem is that I keep getting this `Incompatible types issue` error for the int in the array and I am not sure how to fix it since I am a newbie. Anyone could help?

```
class Building {
    String Name;
    String Addres;
    private int floors;

    Building(String N, String A, int F) {
        Name = N;
        Addres = A;
        floors = F;
    }

    public void SetFloors(int f) {
        if (f <= 0)
            floors = 1;
        else
            floors = f;
    }

    public int GetFloors() {
        return floors;
    }

    void Print() {
        System.out.print("Name=" + Name + "Addres=" + Addres + "floors=" + floors);
    }
}

class TradingCenter extends Building {
    String Owner;
    String Brands[] = {"Brand"};

    TradingCenter(String N, String A, int F, String O, String B[]) {
        super(N, A, F);
        Owner = O;
        Brands = B;
    }
}

class SportCenter extends Building {
    String Sports[] = {"Sport"};
    String Teams[] = {"Team"};

    SportCenter(String N, String A, int F, String S[], String T[]) {
        super(N, A, F);
        Sports = S;
        Teams = T;
    }
}

class DemoBuilding {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Building arr[] = new Building[3];
        arr[0] = new TradingCenter("Mall Plovdiv", "Smirnenski", 3, "Unknown", "Brand");
        arr[1] = new SportCenter("ATLETIK", "Trakia", 1, "Sport1", "Team3");
        arr[2] = new TradingCenter("Paradise Mall", "Sofia, bul. Cherni vruh 100", 5, "Unknown", "Brand");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i].Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exact error message, which includes line numbers. Also, Java convention is to start method names with lowercase, and tools will be more helpful if you follow that convention.

Comment: `"(int)3"` is a String and not an int. Use just `3` instead. And `"Brand 2"` is just a String and not a String array. This must be fixed as well.

Comment: I tried that but same error appeared

Comment: You have to fix that for all three entries. And don't forget to fix the last argument `"Brand 2"`. Also, please read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), because variables and methods should start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because instead of passing int's as parameter,you are actually passing a String. Also,instead of passing a String[], you're simply passing Strings.

Your definition for TradingCenter constructor is

```
TradingCenter(String N, String A, int F, String O, String B[])  
// 3rd argument is supposed to be of type int here and the last(5th) argument is supposed to be of type String[]
```

Your definition for SportCenter constructor is

```
SportCenter(String N, String A, int F, String S[], String T[])
// 3rd argument is supposed to be of type int here and the second-last(4th) and the last(5th) argument is supposed to be of type String[]
```

Check these :-

```
arr[0]=new TradingCenter("Mall Plovdiv","Smirnenski","(int)3","Unknown","Brand 2");   
//  "(int)3" is a String,not int; "Brand 2" is not a String Array
arr[1]=new SportCenter("ATLETIK","Trakia","(int)1","Sport 1","Team 3"); 
//  "(int)1" is a String,not int; "Unknown" & "Brand 2" are Strings,not the String[]
arr[2]=new TradingCenter("Paradise Mall","Sofia, bul. Cherni vruh 100","(int)5","Unknown","Brand 2");
//  "(int)5" is a String,not int; "Brand 2" is not a String Array
```

> To simply use **3,1,5** as an **integer**, **pass 3,1,5 directly without quotes in the constructor calling** .
>
> Also,to use **"Unknown"** and **"Brand 2"** as **String[]**, **pass them as
>   new String[]{"Unknown} and new String[]{"Brand 2"} in the constructor**.

Comment: @DanielaGocheva-Because you've error with passing String Arrays too,please check my latest edit. My last paragraph summarises what you should do to avoid the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this statement

```
 arr[1] = new SportCenter("ATLETIK", "Trakia", "(int)1", "Sport 1", "Team 3");
```

`"(int)1"` This doesn't convert String **1** into integer , It is still the String .

Use This wherever needed

```
 arr[1] = new SportCenter("ATLETIK", "Trakia", 1, "Sport 1", "Team 3");
```

**and for Parsing String into Integer**

```
Integer inputAsInteger=Integer.parseInt(InputString)
```

**Update**

Another error is you are passing **String** in a **String Array**

You need to pass like this

```
arr[1] = new SportCenter("ATLETIK", "Trakia", 1, new String[]{"Sport 1"}, new String[]{"Team 3"});
```

Comment: Great! It worked, but now I have issues for String can not be converted to String[].And if I remove the "" I get error that ; is expected...

Comment: @shekharsuman my mistake , Thanks for pointing that out , I have corrected it , actually didn't seen it .

Comment: @shekharsuman , Where i think `new String[]{"Team 3"}` is perfectly fine
and that parantheses is for the complete  constructor call not for this array

Comment: @tom ahh actually too much mess around , so haven't noticed that too and yes shekharsuman i also didn't got your parantheses point

Comment: @shekharsuman It took you some time :P. Btw: we should clean up here, because the problems got solved on this answer, as well.

Comment: @Tom- Except this one, I did clean all.

Answer (score 0):

The value is passed is A String i.e. "(int)3". Anything inside the " " is considered as a String. But your constructor excepts a integer value.
So either change the constuctor parameter to String or pass it as integer (without quotes).

P.S. If you want to convert a  String into int use Integer.parseInt(str);
e.g.

```
String str = "8";
int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Value of i is now 8.

Comment: Great! It worked, but now I have issues for String can not be converted to String[].And if I remove the "" I get error that ; is expected...

Answer (score 0):

The constructors you use in your main method do not match the types listed in your classes.

You attempt to construct TradingCenter in your main method with five consecutive string parameters, but, your class definition of Trading Center calls for:

(String, String, int, String, String[])

Similar issue exists with SportCenter...the constructor does not match the class definition.